# OnLayout to get image Dimensions crash on second render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

i need a bit of help. Im trying to implement a screen in React native to place 'Tags' like instagram does in his photos. My workaround to this problem is to get the current image onLayout props and render based on that info. The screen takes the image width and height, and places the tags in the equivalent precentaje location of the image. It works just fine until i re open the Tagging screen a second time and the app just crash...

**The reson of the crash** it's because im styling the positions of the tags dynamiclly in the styled component (left:'X'px, top: 'X'px), but as i open the Tagging screen a second time, the onLayout of my image returns an undefined and the styled component crashes at trying to set left: 'undefined'px (or top)

i tried everything and i'm out of ideas... Here is the code im using (Sorry, it's a mess...)

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  LayoutRectangle,
  NativeTouchEvent,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from '../../styles';
import LazyImage from '../LazyImage';

import {TagsContainer, TouchWrapper, TagItem} from './styled';

interface iTags {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  locationX: number;
  locationY: number;
}

interface iProps {
  imageUri: string;
  tagsArray: Array<iTags>;
  onTouch: (percentX: number, percentY: number) => void;
  onDeleteTag: (Tag: iTags) => void;
}

const ImageTaged: React.FC<iProps> = (props) => {
  const [isImageLoading, setImageLoading] = useState(true);
  const [getLayout, setLayout] = useState<LayoutRectangle>(
    {} as LayoutRectangle,
  );

  function handleLayout(layout: LayoutRectangle) {
    setLayout(layout);
  }

  function handleEvent(e: NativeTouchEvent) {
    const {width, height} = getLayout;
    const percentageX = Number(((e.locationX * 100) / width).toFixed(2));
    const percentageY = Number(((e.locationY * 100) / height).toFixed(2));
    props.onTouch(percentageX, percentageY);
  }

  function deleteTag(tag: iTags) {
    props.onDeleteTag(tag);
  }

  function handleLoadEnd() {
    setImageLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <TagsContainer
      onTouchStart={({nativeEvent}) =>
        isImageLoading ? undefined : handleEvent(nativeEvent)
      }>
      <LazyImage
        sourceUri={props.imageUri}
        onLayout={handleLayout}
        onLoadEnd={handleLoadEnd}
      />

      {props.tagsArray &&
        props.tagsArray.map((c: iTags) => (
          <TagItem
            key={c.id}
            locationX={(c.locationX * getLayout.width - 22) / 100}
            locationY={(c.locationY * getLayout.height) / 100}
            onTouchStart={() => deleteTag(c)}>
            <View style={styles.tagTriangle} />
            <View style={styles.tagUserView}>
              <Text style={styles.tagListText}>
                {c.name.length > 10
                  ? c.name.substring(0, 11) + '. . .'
                  : c.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TagItem>
        ))}
    </TagsContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  /
  tagTriangle: {
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    left: 7,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderLeftWidth: 7,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 7,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(244, 147, 144, 0.8)',
    borderBottomWidth: 7,
  },
  tagUserView: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(244, 147, 144, 0.8)',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(244, 147, 144, 0.8)',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 3,
    paddingBottom: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  tagListText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '800',
  },
});

export default ImageTaged;
```

And just in case the Tag styled component used to render the Tag

```js
export const TagItem = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  top: ${(props) => `${props.locationY}px`};
  left: ${(props) => `${props.locationX}px`};
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

The component basiclly is receiving an Array of tags it needs to display in a modal when the user touches the Image, then the user chooses an option from the displayed Modal and the tag gets displayed on top of the Image.

I took this exact concept from a npmjs.com package called 'react-native-image-tagging-same-like-instagram'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implement the TagItem but it is clear that it cant accept undefined as locationX or locationY. so I think you can pass 0 for example if the coordinates haven't been calculated. and in the tagItem check if it is 0 then simply hide the tag.

locationX={c && c.locationX && getLayout && getLayout.width ? (c.locationX * getLayout.width - 22) / 100 : 0}

locationY={c && c.locationY && getLayout && getLayout.height ? (c.locationY * getLayout.height) / 100 : 0}

Comment: Could you try to maybe make it more obvious that this is an answer? The beggining sentence is very misleading.

Comment: The second Code Snippet is the TagItem Implementation. I'm using Styled Components. Also the problem is the onLayout method. It returns undefined the next time i call it. I think it's because it only works once on component mounting but im not sure

Comment: I think you shouldn't pass undefined to your styled component and onLayout sometimes returns undefined. so you should handle this. for example you can check if it is undefined then pass 0 as I did

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answers. I just fixed the issue because the Tags tryes to display themselves before onLayout method was called, so they returned undefined to the stylesheet, and therefore, the error.

Thanks to some answers and some thinking trough, i realized all i had to do is, like Alireza replied, check if layout Obj != undefined before rendering the tags. So dumb from my part haha.

Thanks, now the code is working